ImportError: cannot import name 'Microsoft365DefenderBackend' from 'sigma.backends.microsoft365defender' (unknown location)
How to fix the below error
Python script
import os
import datetime
from sigma.rule import SigmaRule
from sigma.backends.microsoft365defender import Microsoft365DefenderBackend

# Put in the directory containing all the sigma rules
rules_directory = 'sigma/rules/windows/process_creation/proc_creation_win_acccheckconsole_execution.yml'

# Create a folder to store all the translated .md files, if it does not exist already
output_directory = 'KQL - Windows Process Creation'
os.makedirs(output_directory, exist_ok=True)

# List all .yml files in the specified directory
yaml_files = [f for f in os.listdir(rules_directory) if f.endswith('.yml')]

# Initialize the Microsoft365DefenderBackend instance outside the loop for efficiency
m365def_backend = Microsoft365DefenderBackend()

# Get the current date and time

# Loop through each .yml file and process the rules
for yaml_file in yaml_files:
    with open(os.path.join(rules_directory, yaml_file), 'r') as file:
        try:
            # Read the YAML content and create a SigmaRule object
            sigma_rule_orig = SigmaRule.from_yaml(file.read())

            # Translate the rule using Microsoft365DefenderBackend
            translated_content += m365def_backend.convert_rule(sigma_rule_orig)[0]

            # Create a unique file name with .md extension based on the original .yml file name
            md_file_name = os.path.splitext(yaml_file)[0] + '.md'

            # Write the translated content in a Markdown file with KQL section in a code block
            with open(os.path.join(output_directory, md_file_name), 'w') as md_file:
                md_file.write('```kusto\n')
                md_file.write(translated_content)
                md_file.write('\n```\n')

                # Append the original content below the translated content with the entire Sigma rule pre-translation. Also includes a nice heading
                md_file.write('\n\n# Original Sigma Rule:\n')
                file.seek(0)
                md_file.write('```yaml\n')
                md_file.write(file.read())
                md_file.write('```\n')

            print(f"Translated rule with original content written to {os.path.join(output_directory, md_file_name)}")
        except Exception as exc:
            print(f"Error occurred while processing {yaml_file}: {exc}")
            continue

output
root@DESKTOP-EKE1BE0:/home/jilin# python3 sig_convert_win_process_create_markdown.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sig_convert_win_process_create_markdown.py", line 4, in <module>
    from sigma.backends.microsoft365defender import Microsoft365DefenderBackend
ImportError: cannot import name 'Microsoft365DefenderBackend' from 'sigma.backends.microsoft365defender' (unknown location)

Vwerifed below steps.
root@DESKTOP-EKE1BE0:/home/jilin# sigma list formats kusto
+---------+-------------------------------------+
| Format  | Description                         |
+---------+-------------------------------------+
| default | Kusto Query Language search strings |
+---------+-------------------------------------+
root@DESKTOP-EKE1BE0:/home/jilin# sigma  list
+----------------------+----------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+--------------+
| Identifier           | Type     | State   | Description                                                  | Compatible? | Capabilities |
+----------------------+----------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+--------------+
| ibm-qradar-aql       | backend  | stable  | IBM QRadar backend for conversion into AQL queries. Contains | no          | 0            |
|                      |          |         | mappings for fields and logsources                           |             |              |
| rclinuxedr           | pipeline | stable  | Red Canary LinuxEDR pipeline that converts fields to         | yes         | 0            |
|                      |          |         | Telemetry Search mapping.                                    |             |              |
| cortexxdr            | backend  | stable  | Cortex XDR backend that generates XQL queries.               | yes         | 0            |
| carbonblack          | backend  | stable  | Carbon Black backend that supports queries for both          | yes         | 0            |
|                      |          |         | Enterprise EDR (fka Threat Hunter) and EDR (fka Response)    |             |              |
| sentinelone          | backend  | stable  | SentinelOne backend that generates Deep Visibility queries.  | yes         | 0            |
| sentinelone-pq       | backend  | stable  | SentinelOne backend that generates PowerQuery queries.       | yes         | 0            |
| splunk               | backend  | stable  | Splunk backend for conversion into SPL and tstats data model | yes         | 3            |
|                      |          |         | queries as plain queries and savedsearches.conf              |             |              |
| insightidr           | backend  | stable  | Rapid7 InsightIDR backend that generates LEQL queries.       | no          | 0            |
| qradar               | backend  | stable  | IBM QRadar backend for conversion into AQL and extension     | no          | 0            |
|                      |          |         | packages.                                                    |             |              |
| elasticsearch        | backend  | stable  | Elasticsearch backend converting into Lucene, ES|QL (with    | yes         | 3            |
|                      |          |         | correlations) and EQL queries, plain, embedded into DSL or   |             |              |
|                      |          |         | as Kibana NDJSON.                                            |             |              |
| opensearch           | backend  | stable  | Opensearch backend converting into Lucene queries and        | no          | 0            |
|                      |          |         | Opensearch alerting rules.                                   |             |              |
| ala-socprime         | backend  | devel   | Azure Log Analytics backend with Windows log support         | no          | 0            |
|                      |          |         | maintained by SOC Prime.                                     |             |              |
| stix                 | backend  | devel   | STIX backend converting into plain STIX queries. Contains    | no          | 0            |
|                      |          |         | mappings for STIX 2.0 and STIX Shifter taxonomies.           |             |              |
| loki                 | backend  | stable  | Loki backend for conversion into Loki LogQL queries (plain   | yes         | 2            |
|                      |          |         | and ruler YAML for alerts) and pipelines with mappings for   |             |              |
|                      |          |         | Grafana and promtail Sysmon data.                            |             |              |
| windows              | pipeline | stable  | Windows logsource to Channel field and generic logsource to  | yes         | 0            |
|                      |          |         | Windows audit events mapping.                                |             |              |
| sysmon               | pipeline | stable  | Mapping from generic log sources to Sysmon events.           | yes         | 0            |
| crowdstrike          | backend  | stable  | CrowdStrike Logscale backend and pipelines for CrowdStrike   | yes         | 0            |
|                      |          |         | Falcon platform and Falcon Data Replicator (FDR) logs.       |             |              |
| ossem                | pipeline | devel   | Mapping from OSSEM to Sigma taxonomy.                        | no          | 0            |
| powershell           | backend  | testing | PowerShell backend converting into PowerShell queries.       | no          | 0            |
| microsoft365defender | backend  | stable  | Microsoft 365 Defender (formally mdatp) backend and pipeline | yes         | 0            |
|                      |          |         | for conversion of log sources with Sysmon field schema to    |             |              |
|                      |          |         | Microsoft Advanced Hunting Queries in Kusto Query Language   |             |              |
|                      |          |         | (KQL)                                                        |             |              |
| hawk                 | backend  | testing | HAWK.io MDR backend and pipeline for conversion of log       | no          | 0            |
|                      |          |         | sources to HAWK.io BETree queries.                           |             |              |
| datadog              | backend  | testing | Datadog Cloud SIEM backend and pipeline for conversion of    | no          | 0            |
|                      |          |         | log sources to Datadog Query Syntax                          |             |              |
| dictquery            | backend  | stable  | DictQuery backend to convert sigma to dictquery query        | no          | 0            |
|                      |          |         | strings                                                      |             |              |
| sqlite               | backend  | testing | SQLite and Zircolite backend                                 | yes         | 0            |
| uberagent            | backend  | stable  | uberAgent backend                                            | yes         | 0            |
| panther              | backend  | devel   | Panther sdyaml backend                                       | yes         | 0            |
| trellix_helix        | backend  | devel   | Trellix Helix Backend                                        | yes         | 0            |
| quickwit             | backend  | devel   | Quickwit Backend                                             | yes         | 0            |
| netwitness           | backend  | testing | NetWitness Backend that generates application rules          | yes         | 0            |
| logpoint             | backend  | stable  | Logpoint Pysigma Backend                                     | yes         | 0            |
+----------------------+----------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+--------------+
root@DESKTOP-EKE1BE0:/home/jilin# sigma list formats kusto
+---------+-------------------------------------+
| Format  | Description                         |
+---------+-------------------------------------+
| default | Kusto Query Language search strings |
+---------+-------------------------------------+
root@DESKTOP-EKE1BE0:/home/jilin# sigma plugin install microsoft365defender
Successfully installed plugin 'microsoft365defender'
pySigma version is compatible with sigma-cli


@toyota Regarding your edit, I strongly recommend using code fences instead of 4 spaces, so that you get smaller diffs and easier manual syntax highlighting. I had to fix the formatting here and rolling back was the easiest way to do it.

Please read [ask] and [mre]. You have way too much code here for what you're asking, and we need at least some context for what you're doing before seeing your code sample. Making these changed in an [edit] will increase your chances of attracting good answers.

@wjandrea. Thank. I didn't even see output.
